# Java: Trying to use a custom font is Stream Closed

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, custom-font

I am trying to create a custom font in java and I have tried so many different methods, but it just does not work when I go to export the jar. Here is my current code:

```
Font font = null;
try {
    font = Font.createFont(0, new File("res/fonts/PlayTheGame.ttf"));
    font.deriveFont(20f);
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Font fntPlayTheGame = font.deriveFont(0, 40f);

lblTitle = new JLabel("Cell Defender");
lblTitle.setFont(fntPlayTheGame);
```

The font works inside of eclipse, but when I go to run it after compilation it says that it cannot read that. I have tried using an `InputStream` and other stuff, but it just doesn't work.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Assuming that the font is a internal resource, you should be using `getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("res/fonts/PlayTheGame.ttf")` instead

Comment: that just gives me `java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I got it, it helps when you use the path as `/fonts/<font>.ttf` instead of having `res` before the first slash.

Comment: remove this question all together than